# how can I know which shape key drivers are associated with one of my bone?

Tags: rigging, drivers, shape-keys

When inspecting facial rigging, how can I find out which shape key drivers are associated with the mouth bones? I have created several shape keys around the mouth, each corresponding to the nearby mouth bones.